# Is there any way to warp with AE and use it for Lottie?

Tags: lottie, after-effects

I know that effects under AE are not working with Lottie.
Nevertheless, I want to create an effect like the Warp Effect or the Bend Effect in AE and export it to Lottie.

But because this doesn't work I thought I could build something similar with expressions and export it again later with "Convert to Keyframes". But I only saw the wiggle expression. Perspective warping does not seem to be possible.
Is there a kind of path expression that can be used to bend in perspective?

Thanks in advance